# Can't load a json file in threejs

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I have been following a video to load a json image in threejs. However when I follow the code exactly in the video it doesn't show anything in the browser when I try with my own image. The image is a json file that I downloaded from the site clara.io.

Provided is the relevant code from my js file which I have used.

```
<script src="js/ObjectLoader.js"></script>
<script>


            var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

            loader.load
            (
                'models/standard-male-figure.json',

                function(object)
                {
                    scene.add(object);
                }
            );


            camera.position.z = 3;
</script>
```

Here is the errors from the console. I think the video might be outdated but I don't know how to solve.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

three.js:22676 THREE.WebGLRenderer 104

three.js:38584 THREE.ObjectLoader: You have to import LegacyJSONLoader in order load geometry data of type "Geometry".



three.js:38598 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'uuid' of undefined
    at ObjectLoader.parseGeometries (three.js:38598)
    at ObjectLoader.parse (three.js:38274)
    at Object.onLoad (three.js:38244)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.js:34554)
```

Answer (score 2):

`JSONLoader` was removed from the `three.js` core at the end of last year and renamed to `LegacyJSONLoader`. The file is now located in the [examples directory](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/deprecated/LegacyJSONLoader.js).

Please download the file and include it into your project which should hopefully solve your issue. However, you should consider to avoid the usage of legacy JSON files which were probably created with the likewise deprecated Blender JSON exporter. Read the following guide from the official `three.js` documentation for more information about better alternatives like `glTF`.

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models

`three.js R103`

Comment: Whats the best way to include it with es6 imports and use it with npm?

Comment: Try it with this import statement: `import { LegacyJSONLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/deprecated/LegacyJSONLoader.js';`